# Excel Graph Breakeven intercept point

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the intercept point on two lines in an excel graph. They are non-linear and excel doesnt seem to have a built in feature to display this value.

Comment: you could enter the equation of the two line and then use a cell to subtract one equation from the other.  Then use goal seek to vary the X value until the difference between equations is 0 or very close to it.

Comment: But I want to be able to calculate the breakeven dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Check this VBA example: http://andypope.info/charts/intersection.htm. Hit Alt+F11 to see the macro.